# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA while Shutting down PC on Windows 10

Tags: windows

I have an issue while Shutting Down or Restarting a PC on Windows 10, it shows blue screen with an error: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
and it stops there, I can't shutdown or restart this PC, I have to turn it off by holding on/off button.
PC is DELL OptiPlex 3000, I did ePSA scan check and it didn't find any errors.

Comment: That is typically a driver issue:  Update all drivers with the Dell Driver Update App. If not drivers, you may need to do an OS recovery. Back up first.

Comment: I've updated everything I could.

Comment: It may now that you should try reinstalling Windows.  Backup first.

Comment: I suggest running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight to thoroughly test the memory. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I did test with MemTest86 and it's all fine, now I'm trying to install drviers from 3rd party program instead Dell Update, if that will not help, I will have to reinstall Windows i guess.

Comment: Please zip up a few `.dmp` files from `C:\Windows\Minidump` and post them online for analysis.